# How do you get a String[] from a Room database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dao

Pretty self-explanatory. I have a Room database, one of the tables has a column of type `String`, I want to get all the data in that column and return it as `String[]`. For some reason, that `String[]` is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the command from my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT SubMenuTitle FROM SubMenus WHERE MenuID = :MenuID")
String[] getSubMenus(int MenuID);
```

When I run the query using the sqlite3 binary on my phone, the output is as expected.

Comment: Cant you get a `List`, which is the default and simply transform to an array?

Comment: I... could. Let me try that.

Comment: The `List` seems empty.

Comment: Well now u know that the query might be the problem, right?

Comment: I've run the query on the sqlite3 binary on my phone and it outputs as expected. Where could I be messing up?

Comment: I'm just guessing here but have you tried changing your table name and field names from camelcase to lowercase? 
e.g. `SubMenus` entity will be annotated `@Entity(tableName = "sub_menus")`, `SubMenuTitle` field will be annotated `@ColumnInfo(name = "sub_menu_title")` and `MenuID` will be annotated `@ColumnInfo(name = "menu_id ")`
and your Query will be: `@Query("SELECT sub_menu_title FROM sub_menus WHERE menu_id = :MenuID")`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is many, many years late, but I got around this by altering the code to resemble the following:

```
@Query("SELECT SubMenuTitle FROM SubMenus WHERE MenuID = :MenuID")
LiveData<String[]> getSubMenus(int MenuID);
```

Then, after creating a ViewModel object, the `observe()` method was implemented as follows:

```
vm.getSubMenus(MenuID).observe(this, new Observer<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String[] menus) {
        populateTabs(menus);
    }
});
```

My understanding is that since the database queries take time to run, the instant that `getSubMenus()` is run, nothing is actually returned from the database. My initial flawed understanding was that Room would wait for the database query to finish running before returning the object, but 5 further years of studying has proven that this is not the case. Therefore, the `LiveData<>` wrapper was needed so that the `String[]` could be updated as data came in from the database. However,  I may still be wrong, so someone please correct me if I am.